# How to check, if the the current date and other dates are longer than 1 month ago?

Tags: mysql, datetime, date, intervals

I've got the following query:

```
$data = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT 
c.`id` AS cid,
p.`id` AS pid,p.`email`

FROM `coupons` AS c 
LEFT JOIN `coupons_partners` AS cp ON cp.`cid` = c.`id`
LEFT JOIN `partners` AS p ON p.`id` = cp.`pid`
LEFT JOIN `bills` AS b ON b.`pid` = p.`id`

WHERE 
( 
    CURRENT_DATE() BETWEEN c.`expires` AND ADDDATE(c.`expires`, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
)
OR
( 
    CURRENT_DATE() NOT BETWEEN c.`expires` AND ADDDATE(c.`expires`, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
    AND 
    CURRENT_DATE() BETWEEN b.`date` AND ADDDATE(b.`date`, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
)
ORDER BY b.`id` DESC"));
```

It's kinda messy. I want to do a cronjob and create bills automatically. They should only be created after 1 month a coupon expires (c.`expires` is `DATETIME`) or if the LAST bill (b.`date`) was created 1 month ago.
The thing also is that I don't want to create any bill if the coupon didn't started yet. And this is possible, because I create coupons that'll start in maybe 3 months. So I guess the "Between-Solution" doesn't fit here?

I'm trying to figure it out to do it properly, but now I would appreciate any help.

I would be happy and thankful, if someone could help me out.

Best Regards,

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DATEDIFF

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(month, '2000-02-10','2000-01-10');
```

yields 1 since 02-10 is one month after 01-10

**month** can be changed to **day** to get the number of days instead.

Reference: http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-datediff.html

**UPDATE:**
In MSQL you could use DATEDIFF because it can be passed month as an argument, the MySQL version only returns days. In MySQL you could instead use [PERIOD_DIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_period-diff). **Although it doesn't know about the exact number of days in each month.**

> PERIOD_DIFF(P1,P2)

"Returns the number of months between periods P1 and P2. P1 and P2 should be in the format YYMM or YYYYMM. Note that the period arguments P1 and P2 are not date values."

```
mysql> SELECT PERIOD_DIFF(200802,200703);
        -> 11
```

If you need to know if exactly how many months differ you need to make a multistep calculation. To find out the number of days in a month you could use the [LAST_DAY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) function and from the results extract the day part and use as the basis for further calculations.

```
 LAST_DAY('2003-02-05');
        -> '2003-02-28'
```

Comment: I tried `DATEDIFF (month, CURRENT_DATE(),c.expires)` but he doesn't like `CURRENT_DATE()`. Do you know what I should put there for the current date?

Comment: I guess you didn't mean MySQL? Because like in the MySQL documentary there are only two expressions allowed. So I can get the days with `DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),c.expires)` but not exactly a month with an output of one. Isn't this anyhow possible to transform it to month in MySQL?